# Create Facebook API-like WebView pop-up in Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, callback, webview

I have Facebook and Twitter integration in my app. For Facebook I use the API they provided and for Twitter I open a WebView for Oauth.

To save the Twitter key I get back from Oauth I have to use CallBack. However using CallBack lets the user see a black screen (for less than a second) before going to the activity with the sharing options.

Is there a way I can avoid this black screen.

Or better:

Can I make a WebView pop-up like the Facebook API does? If yes, how can I achieve this and how can I save the key I get back from Oauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem that you and I created a Twitter Login Button library which do the same as the Facebook Login Button provided in the example of the Android API.
You can found the code on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-login-button/).

Basically it display a webview containing Twitter website to allow the user to click on Allow and save the token and token secret. You can easily use this library with Twitter4j for example.